# 500 status code on Website images

Tags: web, browser-cache

I have a website for eg: `abcd.com` which was live since past 3 years. Recently we restructured the whole code and images. 
As I check the `access log in apache` I see `500 http status code` for various images that doesn't exist now. Does it seems that the site is cached on client browser and it hits the server to get the image when the same page url is called ? Or The site is cached by google bot ?  What to do to override this call and stop getting request from such image url request which doesn't exist now ?

eg : `/images/newlanding/f.png` -- doesn't exist and also `folder newlanding` is not present in new folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem : It has something to do with Google Image Proxy .
https://support.google.com/a/answer/3299041?hl=en

Though there is no need to whitelist the URL proxy on google, as the image url doesn't exist now.

Also I wrote the htaccess to redirect the invalid image url on my home page.